# /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/ in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can any one tell me what will be the possible input for user when i will use the below series

`var Str=/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/` series in jquery..

Comment: Thats a regular expression, google regular expressions!

Comment: Please don't tag your question with all popular languages.

Answer (score 6):

That regular expression matches strings that contain letters (A-Z or a-z) or digits (0-9) and no other characters. The string must consist of at least one character, but there is no upper limit on the number of characters.

Examples of matching strings:

- `x`
- `foo`
- `123`
- `ABC00`

Examples of strings that don't match:

- *the empty string* (at least one character is required)
- `foo_bar` (because of the underscore)
- `abc 123` (because of the space)

By the way, instead of writing `{1,}` you should typically use `+`.

You can the regular expression working online at [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/kAGc7FGlCt).

**Related Info**

- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Answer (score 4):

regular expressions are not related to jquery, and:

```
^ - start of string
[a-zA-Z0-9] - lowercase letter, uppercase letter, or digit
{1,} - 1 or more of the previous character class (better written as `+`)
$ - end of the string
```

test it yourself at [regexr](http://regexr.com?333co).

Answer (score 0):

I would say from beginning of string to end of string any alpha-numeric character with at least 1 of them appearing.